# Porting to Linux error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token

Tags: c++, linux, porting

Well, I have a class

```
class DLL_LIB a: public b
{

}
```

The gcc says that

> expected initializer before ‘:’ token

I don't understand why. Perhaps it's the proplem with linking the DLL library, but I did so:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define DLL_LIB __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLL_LIB __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Although  I have  made the fake DLL lib I can't avoid the mistake with "expected initializer"

Thank you a  lot!

Comment: You are using MS-specific keywords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of `DLL_LIB` is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
  #ifdef BUILDING_DLL_LIB
    #define DLL_LIB __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define DLL_LIB __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif
#else
  #define DLL_LIB
#endif
```

The purpose of this excercise is as follows:

On Windows, you need to differentiate between "symbol is exported from this DLL" (which is denoted by `__declspec(dllexport)` and must be present when building the DLL) and "symbol is imported from a DLL" (which is denoted by `__declspec(dllimport)` and must be present when including the header in a program linking the DLL).

On Linux, there is no such thing, so the macro must be removed from the header by the preprocessor - hence define it as empty.